# What is the meaning of Andrew words: " One still is all thumbs"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English fantasy movie, Bicentennial Man, *Little Miss* invites *Andrew*
 (Robot) to her marriage.

> Little Miss: It would mean so much to me, if you would be an Usher at
>   my wedding.
>
> Andrew:One is unfamiliar with this term. How does one "ush"?
>
> Little Miss:You help people to their seats. You wear a tuxedo.
>
> Andrew:One would wear clothing?
>
> Little Miss: Yes.
>
> Andrew: One has never been asked to wear clothing. It would be an
>   honor.
>
> Little Miss: Great.
>
> Andrew: **One still is all thumbs**.

Actually before having this conversation, Andrew(robot) lose his thumb while cutting something.

Comment: I googled **all thumbs** without even putting it in quotes or including the word **define**. Every one of the links on the first page of results was to a definition of the idiomatic **all [fingers and] thumbs**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms [all thumbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+thumbs) is an idiom. It means:

> Physically awkward, especially with respect to the hands.

Consequently your sentence means:

> One still is awkward .